# How do I target a specific player in a specific dimension?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make it so that if my friend is in the Nether, it will give him a potion effect, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you are using commands then it doesn't matter what dimension they are in.

Comment: @AwesomeT43 I think they mean ONLY if they are in different dimensions

Comment: I think there is a way in java but I don't know of one with bedrock, sorry.

Comment: @Joachim I think you changed the intention of the post in your last edit - nowhere does it say that it needs to come from the overworld. In fact i was very confused as to what the question asks until I read your edit.

Comment: @Plagiatus Is this better? The original sentence doesn't completely make sense to me, hence the change. Thank you for pointing it out, though.

Comment: @Joachim yes, that seems a lot more in line with the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the 1.19.50 update to `execute`, you can use [`execute in`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#in) to check what dimension a player is in:

```
execute as @a at @s in nether if entity @s[r=1] run say I'm in the nether!
```

Now you can of course replace the `say` command with whatever you want to run instead, in OPs case the `effect` command targeting `@s`.